# How many exception related to pronunciation of 'g'?

Tags: pronunciation

The main rule is saying that words with digraphs 'gy' 'gi' 'ge' should be pronounced as soft 'g', but there are a few exceptions I've met:

lin**ge**r, **ge**t, be**gi**n, big**ge**r, lon**ge**r, dag**ge**r, **ge**ar, unplug**ge**d

Comment: Some people east of New York City pronounce "Long Island" similarly to "longer".  Most Americans do not.

Comment: A reference to the "main rule" would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that letter G in English is almost always a [g] sound, or hard G, before certain suffixes. For example, before -er: not only in *bigger*, but also in *eager* and *digger* (even if the latter one is a noun). Same for -ed morpheme, for example, *long-legged*. Other examples where G is hard before I include *gift* and *girl*. So you see, the rule of soft G before E, I, Y has quite a lot of exceptions.

Answer (score 3):

It is more complex than a simple rule.

I don't think the "main rule" you refer to is correct

> **gy**necology
>   **gi**ll
>   **ge**t

are all hard **g**s,

Though,

> biolo**gy**
>   **gi**ant
>   bei**ge**

are soft **g**s.

Also consider that in

> Pittsbur**gh**

**gh** is a hard **g**, but in

> cou**gh**

it has an "f" sound.